# How can I set Discord to always show a custom message without it being overwritten when I launch a game?

Tags: discord

I have notepad opened and added as a game, while having its name changed to "with your feelings.." so my message is "Playing with your feelings..".

Whenever I play another game, it will instantly change my custom message and it will say "Playing Counter-Strike: Global Offensive" instead. I want to make it so my custom message, "Playing with your feelings..", is shown no matter what other game is on. I don't want my custom message to get changed to "Playing Counter-Strike:Global Offensive" nor any other message. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: *[Comments cleaned up]* - Hi all! This duplicate situation appears to be resolved however if any further discussion needs to take place please raise a question on [meta] :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand what you are asking for, and I admit it is a pretty cool (and nasty, in your case) idea. However, I don't think you can play a game Discord recognizes while having another custom message displayed.

The thing is, **Discord displays only the game you played most recently**, eg. the game you are playing currently.

Sadly, having the Notepad in the foreground would make your game unusable, so you now have to choose between playing a game and being the cool kid on Discord. Or, alternatively, change the file name of the game you are playing so Discord no longer recognizes it. I will not show how to do that, though (I don't know how, and I don't even know if it is possible without creating other problems).